# Append Min values of Block of Rows as a new column

Tags: r, for-loop, append, min

I have the following data

```
head(datakurz)

Datum Abfluss       days
1 1968-01-01   0.681 1968-01-01
2 1968-01-02   0.610 1968-01-02
3 1968-01-03   0.610 1968-01-03
4 1968-01-04   0.790 1968-01-04
5 1968-01-05   0.904 1968-01-05
6 1968-01-06   3.720 1968-01-06
....
....
....
```

I want to calculate the `min` values of each 5 rows , so basically
min of `(0.681,0.610,0.610,0.790,0.904) = 0.610`

this is done by my function

```
Datum <- datad$days[1:100]
Abfluss <- datad$q[1:100]
datakurz <- data.frame(Datum, Abfluss)

datakurz$days <- as.Date(datakurz$Datum, format="%Y-%m-%d")
class(datakurz$days)

head(datakurz)

# BlÃ¶cke gleicher GrÃ¶ÃŸe (window size) und deren Minima berechnen

#minimum <- numeric(ws)

zaehler <-  nrow(datakurz) / 5 #Anzahl Zeilen Datensatz durch ws teilen -> Anzahl BlÃ¶cke
azeile <- 1
ezeile <- 5

for(i in 1:zaehler){
  minimum <- min(datakurz$Abfluss [azeile:ezeile])
  print(minimum)
  azeile <- azeile+5
  ezeile <- ezeile+5
}
```

This generates the following output

```
[1] 0.61 
[1] 0.828
[1] 0.681
[1] 1.41
[1] 0.79
[1] 0.904
[1] 0.828
[1] 0.718
[1] 0.904
[1] 0.79
[1] 0.944
[1] 1.03
[1] 0.866
[1] 1.07
[1] 1.07
[1] 1.25
[1] 0.944
[1] 0.828
[1] 0.79
[1] 1.07
```

so basically `0.61` is the min of the first 5 values `0.828` is the min value of the next block auf 5 values and so on...

Now I want to append these values as a column to the data frame, but just the min. value of each block of 5 values (the rest should be `null`)

Desired output

```
Datum Abfluss       days         min
1 1968-01-01   0.681 1968-01-01  NULL
2 1968-01-02   0.610 1968-01-02  0.610
3 1968-01-03   0.610 1968-01-03  0.610
4 1968-01-04   0.790 1968-01-04  NULL
5 1968-01-05   0.904 1968-01-05  NULL
6 1968-01-06   3.720 1968-01-06  ...
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave` to find the `min` for a group of 5.

```
D$min <- ave(D$q, (seq_len(nrow(D))-1) %/% 5, FUN=function(x)
 ifelse(x==min(x), x, NA))
D
#    q min
#1   1   1
#2   2  NA
#3   3  NA
#4   4  NA
#5   5  NA
#6   6   6
#7   7  NA
#8   8  NA
#9   9  NA
#10 10  NA
#11 11  11
#12 12  NA
#13 13  NA
#14 14  NA
#15 15  NA
```

Data:

```
D <- data.frame(q=1:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using your `for` loop approach you can do :

```
zaehler <-  nrow(datakurz) / 5 
azeile <- 1
ezeile <- 5
datakurz$min <- NA

for(i in 1:zaehler){
  ind <- azeile:ezeile
  minimum <- min(datakurz$Abfluss[ind])
  datakurz$min[ind[datakurz$Abfluss[ind] == minimum]] <- minimum
  azeile <- azeile+5
  ezeile <- ezeile+5
}
```

However, most of the times you don't have to explicitly use a `for` loop in R. For example, the same can be solved with `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)

datakurz %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/5)) %>%
  mutate(min = min(Abfluss), 
         min = replace(min, Abfluss != min, NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) -> result
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 

there I get the following error

`Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "min", value = c(NA, 0.61, 0.61)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 100
> `

Comment: But the dpylr soltution helped! Thank you